# Sublime Text 2 Latextools does not display cite keys

Tags: sublimetext2, biblatex

I am beginning to use Sublime Text 2 with Latextools on a Mac, and trying to typeset a document with a bibliography using Biblatex. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, bibencoding=inputenc, bibstyle=authoryear-ibid, citestyle=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{centralbib.bib}
\begin{document}

\cite{bergemann2011introduction}

\end{document}
```

The document compiles just fine, but in order to insert the citation, I had to write it in by hand; there was no drop-down menu showing me the cite keys. When trying to press cmd+L, ctrl+space, which, to my understanding, should show me a list of all the cite keys, an error message pops up: "No bib files found!" Do I need to add something to the Sublime user settings to make this possible? Currently, the only entry there that refers to autocompletion is:

```
"auto_complete_selector": "source, text",
```

Or is it something I need to change in the Latextools settings? Those are still on the default settings from the installation.

Edit: Found the solution after some more trial and error. The problem lay with the `\addbibresource` command; replacing it with `\bibliography` solved the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the author of the LaTeXTools plugin. A recent update supports `\addbibresource`, so you should be able to use that now. Unfortunately, other biblatex features are not yet supported.

BTW LaTeXTools now has much-improved ref/cite completion. Make sure to read the README and try it out.